# Connecting to Worklight on Android crashes in Debug mode

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

1. Download the native android app: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/AndroidNativeApp.zip
2. Download the worklight server: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/NativeAPIForAndroid.zip
3. Run the android project and make it connect/invoke to worklight server, everything should be fine.
4. If you now execute the android project in 'Debug' mode of eclipse and when you press the 'Connect' button in the android app you should see the following exception:

Am I missing something, are others able to reproduce it ?

[image: Exception stacktrace]

Comment: What class was not found? What does the exception say?

Comment: @DanielGonzalez I believe PathClassLoader is not found

Comment: PathClassLoader is the one that is trying to find whatever class that is not being found (the method findClass takes a string with the name of the class). Try what Thejaswini said below and see if it works. If not, please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001610/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-pathclassloader-findclass-android to see an example of how it fails to find a class. Logcat should tell you which class is not being found by the PathClassLoader.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez What Thejaswini works and Logcat says: Could not find class 'com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap', referenced from method com.worklight.common.security.WLDeviceAuthManager.csrCertificateRecieveFailed

Answer (score 0):

I too get the same exception, but when I resume (F8) it continues and connection happens successfully. Have you tried to resume.

[image]

Comment: Yup that does help :)